# is there any way to Build up Heroku For R code like Python

Tags: r, heroku

I have Made a mL model to complete an end to end project. I know how to run heroku for python. I can not find any way to do with R code for Heroku. can Any one help me with this. I want to deploy the R code for Heroku. how can I do it? How can I set up pickle file like python for R

Comment: You might be able to put it inside a shiny app and deploy as described [here](https://steve-condylios.medium.com/how-to-move-your-r-shiny-app-on-to-the-web-using-heroku-fd54b7d2ad88) (note the comment showing how to install packages)